# Android Change rotation of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am having a problem when the screen is normal the image looks okay on the android phone but when i shift to landscape it occupy the space of the Navigation header bar.
Also when i rotate phone it takes me back to the home or Main Activity i don't what that. the following is the Main-fragment.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fred.yeno.MainFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/puAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dice" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MAnifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fred.yeu">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The following is the MainFragment.java

```
package com.example.fred.yenu;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

}
```

[image: Potrait Image]

[image: Potrait]

Comment: can you put the code of the landscape layout plz

Comment: you want remove the possibility of rotation?
Or What?
Add the code of the Fragment maybe you are wrong with declaration of Toolbar or something else, same for the fragment xml.

Comment: When rotate the screen, the activity will create over again.

Comment: No it should rotate but maintain the page that i have navigated into and not direct me to the Main-fragment

Comment: can you post more code?
I have an app with a view pager with tabs in the Toolbar and if i rotate the screen portrait-landscape and viceversa the screen focus still remain in the same fragment, and i have 5 fragments with this layout.
How you declare the fragments in the Manifest?
Have you added some parents relationship?

Comment: what code do you want me to post @Dario

Comment: Fragment.java and the layout of the fragment.
The code that you post, what is?
Post the class that manage the Fragments maybe something is wrong

Comment: I have added the java code @Dario

Comment: Only this?
You say that when you change orientation the app go back to the first fragment, right?

And i see that the package it's different in the 3 files that you post.
Yeno yenu yeu....it's normal?

Comment: they are all the same man all the same @Dario and yes that the only code that i have writen

Comment: `tools:context="com.example.fred.yeno.MainFragment"` and `package="com.example.fred.yeu"` and `package com.example.fred.yenu;` are different :D .
When you say "When i rotate back the phone the app go back to the main activity or home".
You don't have others Activity, i don't understand what happen exactly.
You have only one Fragment (so 1 screen visualizzation), when you change the screen orientation the image cover all screen and if you change again, the app change activity?
Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: @Dario i have added  a picture

Comment: Ok, i understand the problem, when you change rotation in landscape you lose the Toolbar, and whn you turn back to portrait you see the Toolbar again or it's lost?

Comment: You don't have an Activity, only a Fragment.
Why don't use Activity?

Comment: Help me with Activity @Dario

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have defined the `Toolbar` to your `Fragment`, and you don't know how and when use `Fragment`.
I suggest you to Download Android studio (if you had it, update SDK and IDE at last version).

After that crete a new project with `Blank Activity` and start you project from there.

After if you want/need, you can add 1,2 or N `Fragments` to your `Activity`.

I Suggest you to read the official documents that i link to you below:

[Build your first app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

[Activitys](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

[Build dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

If you read this Documents you have the basic for start your App and you can see that the problem that you have disappear.